# Cannot get element of a certain class inside a querySelector

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I can't seem to extract the price in the "span" tag inside the "grand totals" section. It's really odd because getElementsByTagName returns null?

```js
var total = document.querySelector("tbody").getElementsByClassName("grand totals");
console.log(total.innerHTML);
```

```html
<tbody>

  <tr class="totals sub">
    <th data-bind="i18n: title" class="mark" scope="row">Subtotal</th>
    <td class="amount">
      <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': title}" data-th="Subtotal">£524.00</span>
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr class="totals-tax">
    <th data-bind="text: title" class="mark" colspan="1" scope="row">Tax</th>
    <td data-bind="attr: {'data-th': title}" class="amount" data-th="Tax">
      <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()">£104.80</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="grand totals">
    <th class="mark" scope="row">
      <strong data-bind="i18n: title">Order Total</strong>
    </th>
    <td data-bind="attr: {'data-th': title}" class="amount" data-th="Order Total">
      <strong><span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()">£628.80</span></strong>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: It's probably because you didn't specify the `table` element to enclose the `tbody` element in.

Comment: Use `document.querySelector("tbody").querySelectorAll(".grand.totals");`

Comment: A NodeList - or HTMLCollection, I can't remember - has no `innerHTML` property, apart from other problems, so you'd need to iterate over the nodes returned.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's an issue with your `<tbody>` element missing the required `<table>` element as its parent:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <!-- Contents of tbody -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Alternatively, you should replace your `<tbody>` element with the `<table>` element:

```html
<table>
  <!-- Contents of table -->
</table>
```

---

And as noted by @JesusPacheco's answer, [`Element.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) returns an array of elements, as indicated in the documentation on MDN:

> The `Element` method `getElementsByClassName()` returns a live `HTMLCollection` which contains every descendant element which has the specified class name or names.

(Note: `Document.getElementsByClassName` is equivalent to `Element.getElementsByClassName`)

Hence you'll have to access the specified index in order to retrieve its properties:

```js
// NOTE: This is demo code!
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('my-class another-class');
// Retrieve the length of els:
console.log(els.length);
// Access the first element's inner HTML:
console.log(els[0].innerHTML);
```

---

Updated code snippet (I'll assume you're intending to retrieve the inner HTML of the first element in the list of returned elements from `getElementsByClassName`):

```js
var total = document.querySelector("tbody").getElementsByClassName("grand totals");
// getElementsByClassName returns an array, so you can't just
// log the inner HTML
// console.log(total.innerHTML);
console.log(total[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="totals sub">
      <th data-bind="i18n: title" class="mark" scope="row">Subtotal</th>
      <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': title}" data-th="Subtotal">£524.00</span>
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="totals-tax">
      <th data-bind="text: title" class="mark" colspan="1" scope="row">Tax</th>
      <td data-bind="attr: {'data-th': title}" class="amount" data-th="Tax">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()">£104.80</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="grand totals">
      <th class="mark" scope="row">
        <strong data-bind="i18n: title">Order Total</strong>
      </th>
      <td data-bind="attr: {'data-th': title}" class="amount" data-th="Order Total">
        <strong><span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()">£628.80</span></strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, getElementsByClassName return an array of elements.
You have to get the `span` element by its class name, like this:

```js
var total = document.querySelector("tbody").getElementsByClassName("price");
console.log(total[index].innerHTML); // total is an array of "price" class span
```

Comment: No this doesnt work  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null""

Comment: Refactor to document.getElementsByClassName("price")